# Choosing Swift Language for new OS X Project not available

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, new-project

I'm having what is probably a  dumb moment. I've made several Swift apps for iOS and now I wanted to create a Swift app for OS X. When I create a new OS X Project, I am only given the choice for Objective-C in the language drop down menu. Swift is not listed for OS X.

Why would that be? What am I missing? I am running the latest Xcode 6 as well as the latest Yosemite beta.

New iOS Project:
[image: New iOS Project]

New OS X Project:
[image: New OS X Project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been some changes in Xcode 6.0 support for GM. For Xcode 6.0, there will not be support for Swift on OSX. In order to use Swift and target OSX, you need to get Xcode 6.1 for the Member Center.

According to the [Release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_gm_seed_txl4k3/xcode_6_release_notes.pdf)<sup>PDF</sup> for Xcode 6.0 GM:

> A future version of Xcode to be released along with OS X Yosemite will add Swift support for OS X, including playgrounds and REPL. Xcode 6.0 only supports Swift for iOS projects and playgrounds. A beta release of Xcode with Swift support for both OS X and iOS is available at [The Member Center].

It *will* run on Mavericks, so Yosemite is not required.